# How to schedule a operation in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have made the following command that changes channel permissions.

```
    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
    async def unlock(self, ctx):
        perms = ctx.channel.overwrites_for(ctx.guild.default_role)
        perms.send_messages=True
        await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, overwrite=perms)
        await ctx.message.add_reaction(emoji="<a:tick:748476262640779276>")
```

Now I want to know how do I schedule it so that my bot performs it automatically everyday at 10am in a specific channel. I have tried searching for the ways and I found out that I can do it with crontab but I don't know how?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Install schedule with pip:

```
$ pip install schedule
```

You could do something like that:

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("Do something")

schedule.every().day.at("10:00").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```